# MySQL Access denied for Laravel on Docker

Tags: laravel, docker

I want to dockerize my laravel project and have done the configurations but whenever i run `php artisan migrate` command, i get this error

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'admin'@'172.16.238.10' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')`

Clearly it says access is denied for the admin user but I can't really traced where the error is.

Below are the configuration file:

app.dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

COPY composer.lock /var/www

COPY composer.json /var/www

WORKDIR /var/www

COPY database /var/www/database

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git gnupg && \
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    nano \
    vim \
    openssl \
    git \
    curl\
    unzip 

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/

RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" \
    && php composer-setup.php \
    && php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" \
    && php composer.phar install --no-dev --no-scripts \
    && rm composer.phar

COPY . /var/www

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data \
        /var/www/storage \
        /var/www/bootstrap/cache \
        /var/www/public

RUN  apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev \
        libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends \
        && pecl install mcrypt-1.0.2 \
        && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
        && docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt

COPY laravel.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available

RUN ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/laravel.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/

RUN a2dissite 000-default.conf

RUN a2ensite laravel.conf

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN service apache2 restart

CMD php artisan serve --port=8000

EXPOSE 8000
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services: 

     # The Database
    database:
        container_name: mysql_database
        image: mysql:5.7
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            - "MYSQL_DATABASE=laravel"
            - "MYSQL_USER=laravel"
            - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=admin"
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin"
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        networks:
            myapp_net: 
                ipv4_address: 172.16.238.11

    # The Application
    app:
        container_name: laraveldocker
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: app.dockerfile
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./storage:/var/www/storage
        env_file: '.env'
        environment:
            - "DB_HOST=database"
            - "REDIS_HOST=cache"
        depends_on:
            - database
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        networks:
            myapp_net: 
                ipv4_address: 172.16.238.10


    # redis
    cache:
        image: redis:3.0-alpine

volumes:
    dbdata:

networks:
    myapp_net:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
                - subnet: 172.16.238.0/24
```

laravel.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 172.16.238.10

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/public

    <Directory /var/www/>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

.env:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:yS7v+khzJ1GxLVAtpyWd0gG/5SOwoZr/wsXH2h/VH2o=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=172.16.238.11
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=admin
DB_PASSWORD=admin

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: With your current env vars for mysql container, you end up with two users: `laravel` and `root` both having the password `admin`. Ther is no `admin` user.

Comment: Hmmm not sure if this is something you have looked already your DB ip is: 172.16.238.11 and when you tried to connect you tried to connect to 172.16.238.10 with is the APP not the mysql host. Also have user as Laravel not admin. like @Zeitounator mentioned

Answer (score 0):

There is no user named `admin` in database configuration.

Change `"MYSQL_USER=laravel"` to `"MYSQL_USER=admin"`